# Nivo slider in repeater with custom caption

Tags: jquery, asp.net, nivo-slider

I have a client that is a traveling agency who always has special offers and would like to post these special offers on the first page in a slideshow. The picture should be let's say the Eifel tower and the caption on the right should be a box with more info like a title, a price, probably dates and a button. So these offers will always change and it is the client who will manage that. Now the thing is I would like to make it work in a repeater. The pictures are changeing correctly, but the caption is not moving. It get's set on the first element in the datasource and it is stuck like that. I have tried a little example so I will post it here:

```
public partial class TestPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<BindRepeater> source = new List<BindRepeater>
            {
                new BindRepeater {Pic = "Images/TestSlideshow/nemo.jpg", Text = "Text 5", OfferID = 1},
                new BindRepeater {Pic = "Images/TestSlideshow/walle.jpg", Text = "Text 2", OfferID = 2},
                new BindRepeater {Pic = "Images/TestSlideshow/up.jpg", Text = "Text 3", OfferID = 3},
                new BindRepeater {Pic = "Images/TestSlideshow/toystory.jpg", Text = "Text 4", OfferID = 4}
            };

        rptPic.DataSource = source;
        rptPic.DataBind();

        rptCaption.DataSource = source;
        rptCaption.DataBind();
    }

}

public class BindRepeater
{
    public int OfferID { get; set; }
    public string Pic { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
<div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
        <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
            <asp:Repeater ID="rptPic" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div>
                        <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="OfferID" />
                        <img src='<%# Eval("Pic") %>' alt="" title='<%# String.Format("#htmlDiv{0}",Eval("OfferID")) %>' />
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </div>
    </div>
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptCaption">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div id='<%# String.Format("htmlDiv{0}",Eval("OfferID")) %>' class="nivo-html-caption">
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl" Text='<%# Eval("Text") %>' CssClass="label_blue15"></asp:Label>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(window).load(function () {
                $('#slider').nivoSlider({
                    effect: 'random', // Specify sets like: 'fold,fade,sliceDown'
                    animSpeed: 500, // Slide transition speed
                    pauseTime: 5000, // How long each slide will show
                    startSlide: 0, // Set starting Slide (0 index)
                    directionNav: true, // Next & Prev navigation
                    controlNav: true, // 1,2,3... navigation
                    controlNavThumbs: false, // Use thumbnails for Control Nav
                    pauseOnHover: true, // Stop animation while hovering
                    manualAdvance: false // Force manual transitions
                });
            });
        </script>
```

the *htmlcaption* div will have more stuff, like labels, buttons. This was just a dummie.
At this stage the caption is not animated, and I would like to make it somehow that when the image is changing, I get from a datasource the text needed with the proper *OfferID*.
Or maybe there is another approach?
I have also tried one repeater that contains both the image and the caption, also didn't work.

Thanks

Later Edit: I have changed the code, created a repeater for the captions too and tried to set the img title to the id of the div inside the caption repeater. All I get is the pictures sliding and the caption staying on the first one, never changing to the next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, I managed to find the answer. The way to do it with two repeaters is the one above, and the fix to the upper code is that I forgot to give values to the OfferID in the datasource. I will edit that too and then the above code is good to run.